# Don't charge on click Pay in Google pay

Tags: google-pay

I am implementing Google pay in angular and using @google-pay/button-angular. I don't want to deduct amount when he click on Pay button, after showing receipt there will be a button "Proceed to pay". When user click on "Proceed to pay" button, then amount will be deducted from his card. My question is, Is it possible to make that work or I just can't do that?

Answer (score 0):

Google Pay and the Google Pay button doesn't actually process the payment. What it does is returns a payment token that you can then use with your payment service provider to process the payment.

If you don't want to charge the user, then don't call your payment service provider to process the payment.